# What is the difference between -j DROP and -j STEAL?

Tags: iptables

I often see that people set `STEAL` target in iptables rules. It's possible to get this target by installing (on debian) `xtables-addons-common` and `xtables-addons-dkms`. I was curious why people prefer `STEAL` over `DROP`, so I checked the [manual](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=xtables-addons&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20testing%20jessie&format=html&locale=en), but there's only the following info:

```
   STEAL
       Like the DROP target, but does not throw an error like DROP when used
       in the OUTPUT chain.
```

Does anyone know what error? For example, we could take the two following rules:

```
-A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --match multiport ! --dports 80,443 --match set --match-set bt_level1 dst --jump STEAL
```

and:

```
-A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --match multiport ! --dports 80,443 --match set --match-set bt_level1 dst --jump DROP
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Drop sends an error packet when used with the OUTPUT chain. Kind of like how REJECT returns an error packet when used with the INPUT chain. STEAL doesn't.

**EDIT:** Per bahamat, the IPtables extensions are in fact done by the netfilter team.

Comment: These extensions are provided by the netfilter team. They in fact write `iptables` and the kernel modules that go along with it. The code isn't outside because it's by untrusted party. It's because the code is experimental.

Comment: Good to know, I was under the impression it was maintained by an outside group.