# How can I silently drop some outgoing packets?

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm doing some testing of an application I am working on, and I need to be able to **silently** drop outgoing UDP packets for a short period of time to replicate a possible failure mode.

Is there any way to do this?

Note: `iptables` `DROP` **is not silent for outgoing messages!** When a `send()` or similar call is dropped by `iptables`, it returns `EPERM` for some bizarre reason (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136570/268006). Unfortunately, I can't use that answer as my destination is a single hop away).

`xtables-addons` [*used* to have a `STEAL` verb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108847/what-is-the-difference-between-j-drop-and-j-steal), but it got removed a few years ago for no reason I can find.

---

I've now tried using bogus routes in the routing table, and unfortunately, that appears to break *both* directions of comm traffic.
For the test I need to do, I **have** to allow *inbound* UDP traffic, and as soon as I install the bogus route, the streaming incoming packets immediately halt, though the source is still sending them.

Comment: Far from a complete/tidy solution but I've needed similar test condition in the past.  In my case adding a bogus static route to the server I'm connecting worked well.

Comment: @steve - A bogus route appears to break things in *both* directions, and I need to maintain the RX direction's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding dummy interface and setting the route to that interface?

```
# ip link add dummy0 type dummy
# ip link set dev dummy0 up
# ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 dev dummy0
# ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2015ms
```

It always sends packets for any (neighbor or remote) addresses on `dummy0`.

```
# tshark -i dummy0
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'dummy0'
  1   0.000000   10.10.0.59 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1ce0, seq=1/256, ttl=64
  2   1.007348   10.10.0.59 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1ce0, seq=2/512, ttl=64
  3   2.015394   10.10.0.59 -> 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1ce0, seq=3/768, ttl=64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to disallow *incoming* packets that match the route from other interfaces. As such, it doesn't really work (it breaks the open UDP *rx* stream I need to allow to continue).

Answer (score 2):

Adding a route is breaking incoming traffic due to reverse path filtering. Simple solution: disable reverse path filtering on the interface:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
```

(use your incoming interface in place of *`eth0`* above).

You could also use the `REDIRECT` target (send the packet to, e.g., a netcat listening for it—`nc -l -u -p 1234 > /dev/null`). A more complicated version would be NFQUEUE.